# Fire click event on a href through an li click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers

Hope it's easy to understand by using this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xQ9Nz/13/

It does "exist" the $("a.editarLocal",this), but it doesn't trigger the click event.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to do exatly?

Comment: trigger the a.editarLocal when I click anywhere in the li which contains it

Comment: It *does* trigger the click. You've commented out the listener. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARRT3/)

Comment: ... but triggering isn't the same thing as clicking a link. It won't follow the `href`. Is that what you're asking? You'll have to set `window.location.href = $(yourLink).attr('href');`

Comment: @DavidHedlund Please post that as an answer so I can accept it! Thanks a lot, it works now!

Comment: @silentw: Accept Florian's answer if you're happy with it. It seems to say the same thing as I was saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mean "trigger the click", you want the link to work correctly? You can't.

A workaround is to register a click event on the link that redirects using `window.location`.

For example:

```
// Your code somewhere in the onclick of another element
$('#the-link').click()

// Then, register a click event
$('#the-link').on('click', function() {
    window.location.href = this.href
 })
```

Edit: oops, looks like a commenter said it while I was submitting the answer. @David Hedlund: create your answer and I'll delete mine :)

Comment: Bah, formalities. This answer is fine.